# Can you user a WordPress theme framework in .Net Core app

Tags: wordpress, asp.net-core, wordpress-theming

I have created a .NET Core application, but wasn't sure if you could use WordPress theme in a .NET Core application.

I am aware of PeachPie, PHP compiler, however all I am looking is to create a theme on WordPress and use it in my .net core web app.

Comment: This might be better asked on [Wordpress.StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: BTW - https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-use-wordpress-themes-outside-of-wordpress says no, you can't.

Comment: Alternatively, apparently WordPress itself is available for .NET https://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWholeOfWordPressCompiledToNETCoreAndANuGetPackageWithPeachPie.aspx